# Cannot run webpack dev server on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I got a project that was created by someone on Linux and I now cannot run it in windows.

This is the run script:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node -r @babel/register ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server.cmd --config ./webpack.config.development.js
```

And this is the error that shows up. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=development node -r @babel/register ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server.cmd --config ./webpack.config.development.js
D:\Repos\x\y\node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server.cmd:1
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: That does run the webpack dev server, but how am I supposed to combine it with the `node -r @babel/register`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself in the end.

The project just cannot be run on windows directly at this moment.

Maybe it can be run directly, but the easiest solution to this problem at this moment is creating a docker container and running it in the container (`FROM node`).

it is **important** to specify an empty volume in docker-compose for node_modules, so docker doesn't use the node_modules on your windows machine but rather the node_modules created on linux which work correctly.

```
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```